# Eclipse/Java integration not working after Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, java, eclipse

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 this morning.  After the upgrade I fired up Eclipse and noticed that it was lacking Java integration: Java Perspectives were gone, the option to create a new Java project was missing, the menu item to build existing Java projects was grayed out, etc.  Everything was working fine before upgrading.

```
:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

If I can provide any additional helpful info, please let me know.  I'm still relatively new to the Linux/Java world, so thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: the eclipse packages have undergone significant changes between 11.10 and 12.04.  try removing the eclipse ppa and reinstalling eclipse from software center.  it works for me.  if you want java stuff also install the pde package

Comment: I tried uninstalling/installing Eclipse via Software Center and it didn't really change anything, still no Java integration.  Can you clarify what you mean by the PDE Package?  Anything else that I may be missing?

Comment: this: http://i.imgur.com/nMRgS.png

Comment: Ah, gocha.  Thanks for pointing that out, I had it installed pre 12.04 upgrade but didn't reinstall it.  I actually managed to get this working a different way, I just grabbed the latest Eclipse JEE (wanted this anyway) from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php and dropped the contents in /usr/lib/eclipse and everything seems to work out of the box.  I guess I'm not sure whether this will screw with automatic Eclipse updates via Software Center though.

Comment: Looks like that may have been a bad call, I can't install new software from within Eclipse now (I get a pop up that tells me that the installation hasn't been configured properly for software updates).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so it can help the next person!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse is extremely "version sensitive" platform ecosystem.

I've been using eclipse for 9 years, since the 2.x era. Almost every plugin I've used, had to be installed with an **exact version** of its dependencies, any slight variation and the result was an unstable IDE all over.

If you are going to be programming in JEE, I strongly recommend to use the downloaded one from Eclipse's site, whenever possible install plugins through eclipse's update facility. You'll live longer, and happier :)

I'm a JEE developer for the past 6 years, and every time I tried to use Eclipse from repository, the result was awful, too much instability, and many plugins did not worked as expected (Jboss Tools for instance).

I've had some problems recently, running JBossWS, with 3.7.x versions, it often crashed on 64Bit, Mint 12(Ubuntu 11.10), so I decided  to downgrade to Eclipse 3.6.